# How to get a channel's ongoing live stream videos without using search functionality of You Tube Data API

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to get a channel's ongoing live streams information without using Youtube Data API's search functionality.

Using the search API and API KEY I can get the required info but it is a costly operation (100 quotas) and I want to find a low cost way of doing this.

Comment: How about [Youtube Live Streaming API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveStreams)?